# Welcome page is displayed without being redirected to login page

Tags: jsf, j-security-check

I have following web.xml file I kept welcome page into security check so that it would redirect to login page but the welcome page is displayed without user loggin in. Is this the correct way?
[image]

```
<welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/GISPages/welcome.xhtml</welcome-file> 
    </welcome-file-list>

    <resource-ref>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/Gis_WebApp</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    </resource-ref>


    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Protected Pages</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/GISPages/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>registereduser</role-name>
            <role-name>admin</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>

    <login-config>
        <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
        <realm-name>Live</realm-name>
        <form-login-config>
            <form-login-page>/login.xhtml</form-login-page>
            <form-error-page>/noauth.xhtml</form-error-page>
        </form-login-config>
    </login-config>

    <security-role>
        <role-name>registereduser</role-name>
    </security-role>

    <security-role>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </security-role>
```

Comment: Under the `web-resource-collection` tag you have a duplicate entry for `url-pattern`.  This may be the cause of the problem.  Where is the rest of the file?

Comment: @maple_shaft removed those but still same problem. well I have added the image file.

Comment: Just compared it to my configuration. Only difference is that login.xhtml and error.xhtml are also in the protected folder and not outside. Just a guess.

Comment: @MattHandy No difference kept it inside protected folders too

Comment: Which server is it? A folder in the welcome file path is by the way somewhat strange. Although most servers will accept it, the welcome file is initially supposed to be the sole filename/extension of the file which the server should display when a folder is requested, regardless of the requested folder itself. You should actually have `<welcome-file>welcome.xhtml</welcome-file>` as welcome file and somehow perform a redirect from the one in the root folder to the other in the desired folder by a filter or a managed bean (post)constructor.

Comment: (continued) Give changing the `<welcome-file>` setting a try. If that fixes the problem, then it would be a security bug in the server make/version used. Try if necessary different makes/versions to exclude the one and other and finally report it to the server's development team.

Comment: @BalusC I am using Tomcat 7. It displays login page if I put everything under security constrain i.e. "/*"

Comment: shows random URL like *localhost/j_securitycheck* or **http://localhost:7070/NCellLive/rfRes/skinning.ecss.xhtml;jsessionid=E3958E0C42DF25910F1E618D96348505?db=eAE78Y1hMgAGmQJS**

Comment: Your welcome page is /welcome.xhtml, add <url-pattern>/welcome.xhtml</url-pattern>

Comment: In my web.xml I don't have a leading / for welcome-file, as BalusC said, but it is needed in the url-pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Security constraints protects a URL pattern, but in this case due to welcome-file setting your default URL will change to something like http://:port/webcontext/ and welcome.xhtml will be displayed. Whereas as per the URL pattern defined a protected URL should have URL like http://:port/webcontext/GISPages/welcome.xhtml
Since the URL pattern did not match the application server render the page content.

Only solution which worked for me is to check UserPrincipal in prerender event

```
<f:event type="preRenderComponent"
listener="#{bean.forwardToLoginIfNotLoggedIn}" />
```

and redirect to login.xhtml if UserPrincipal returns null.

Apologies for opening an old thread. I recently faced similar issue hence thought that this might be useful to some.